# Python - Search and extract strings from file

Tags: python, string, extract

I have a txt file that I would like to search for strings and extract the output to a file using python. The strings change slightly but are consistent in terms of format in the file e.g.: "**, 12345-008-**" and "**, 15432-002-**"

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use **regex**.

**Ex:**

```
import re
s = "sdfsdfsdf 12345-008-  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsdf 15432-002- sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsd"
print(re.findall("\d{5}\-\d{3}", s))
```

**Output:**

```
['12345-008', '15432-002']
```